# How do I change the input method in guest session?

Tags: guest-session, input-language

I like the concept of having a guest account on the computer, but one thing I would like to know is, if the guest account is customizable? Particularly the language input settings?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Could you please explain a little better why this question needs the [tag:12.04] tag and why it is 12.04 specific?

Comment: @Seth: The original question was about how to customize a 12.04 install, and that's what I'm trying to help with. A central component that affects this is the im-switch package, which was shipped with Ubuntu up to version 12.10, but has been replaced with im-config in 13.04 and going forward. So if we finally figure out a working solution to the problem, it will not be applicable to versions > 12.10.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson On the Stack Exchange we prefer to change the *answer* to work for a certain version, that way when a new version comes out we don't need a whole new question about the same topic, just a new answer if the method has changed.

Comment: @Seth: I see, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the tutorial [Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). As regards language input, the line

```
echo 'setxkbmap se,us' >> $HOME/.profile
```

in `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` is an example of how the keyboard layout for the guest sessions may be specified.

*Edit:*

From your comment I understand that you need to use e.g. IBus. I'm pretty sure it can be done, but I'm on 13.10 now, where the input method configuration works differently, so I can't easily figure out the details.

What's most important, I suppose, is to make sure that IBus is started automatically when you launch a guest session, so that the IBus icon shows up on the menu bar. That should be the case if Chinese is your system wide display language.

*Edit II:*

Assuming that your system default display language is en_US, you may want to try these steps:

- Create the folder `/etc/guest-session`
- Create the file `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` and give it the following contents:

```
# start the IBus daemon automatically
mkdir -p $HOME/.xinput.d
ln -s /etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/ibus $HOME/.xinput.d/en_US
chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME/.xinput.d
```

Hopefully that will make the IBus icon show up on the menu bar when you launch a guest session.

*Edit III:*

I have just rewritten the previously mentioned [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). With the new approach to customizing the guest session feature, this question (and many similar questions) are answered much more easily than before.

So a version neutral answer to this question may now be:

- [Create a special purpose user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Special_purpose_user) in accordance with the tutorial.
- When logged in to the special user account, change the input method settings (and possibly the keyboard layout settings too) to your liking.
- Done.

I tested this successfully on Ubuntu 14.04, and I believe the chances are good that it works fine on 12.04 as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have installed the tarball files, but I am still confused how do I add a specific language input. (in my case, the "Chinese - Chewing" method)

Comment: @Bicycle808: Given that info, I edited my answer. Two questions: 1) Is the IBus icon displayed on the menu bar when you launch a guest session? 2) What's your system default display language?

Comment: 1. When I launch the guest session, there are nothing displayed on the menu bar for inputs.
2. I am setting the system default display language as English, and I prefer to leave it like that, as I could have guests from various countries.

Comment: @Bicycle808: Answer edited again...

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question. But I am quite new to Linux, and I seemed to have installed the tarball files at the "Download" folder, Do you suggests me to install tarball files under the File System/etc folder?

Comment: @Bicycle808: It's fine to extract the tarball in Download. The tarball includes a special installation file. If you follow the instructions in README and run that installation file, the files will end up where they are supposed to. OTOH, installing the tarball is not necessary to try my idea with respect to input methods; you can just follow the steps under "Edit II" in the answer.

Comment: Thank you once again for your comment, I would like to first uninstall guest-session-prefs which I think I installed in the download folder. However, when I "sudo ./uninstall.sh", it said command not found, even though I could see the uninstall.sh in the folder after I "cd" to the local folder. Could you help me with this please?

Comment: @Bicycle808: As it says in the README file, you should first do: cd /usr/share/doc/lightdm/guest-session-prefs-lightdm

Comment: @Bicycle808: I edited my answer again. I think that the "Edit III" approach may help you fix it.